# Access azure file storage from web app without a backend

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to access azure storage via Rest Api, using **only frontend javascript**?

e.g:

1. User tries to load an image stored in azure storage .
2. Redirected to portal.azure.com for logging in.
3. Sent back to my webapp, with the cookies or whatever is needed to generate an authenticated url.

Comment: Yes. Just use AJAX. But you don't log into portal.azure.com, you use the storage accounts REST API directly.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  But how to authenticate? It seems all the solutions in the docs require backend

Comment: Although it's not very secure, for storage accounts you can just use a SAS token

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid wont the user have to keep creating them as they expire? would be best if the user wont have to input anything in the app (e.g google clouds workds via login)

Comment: I've never used google clouds but if you don't have to login then that's anonymous access, which can also be achieved in storage accounts. It's even less secure because anyone who has the URL can get to the resource. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Look at the first line - with a .net backend

Comment: Yeah sorry I saw that (and deleted my comment haha)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your help, will stick around to see if someone managed the flow in the question, and if not, will wake the sleeping giant which is our backend team ):

Comment: This looks more like js-only https://github.com/shawntabrizi/Microsoft-Authentication-with-MSAL.js

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yeah, seems to be a step closer to what I need! been googling for an hour. Will soon know if too good to be true\

Comment: You may also find this useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad.

Comment: @Skarlinski Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: @TonyJu yeah, managed to use msal to get a token, but now cant seem to be able to get the image from the blob using this token. It might be because I am calling the blob rest api wrongly, or an issue with the scope of the access token ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [authenticate access to Azure blobs using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).

Then you will be able to get an access token to access azure storage via Rest Api. Here is an [example](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core) walks you through how to login a user and acquire a token to be used for Microsoft's Graph Api. You can change the Graph Api to storage api.

**Updates:**

The way to get access token. The scope can be `https://storage.azure.com/.default`

[image]

Access private blob with access token. You also need to add the **x-ms-version** header.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will try tommorow. I Keep being one step behind.. hope the default scope helps

Comment: @Skarlinski If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer to help others. Thank you.

Comment: will do of course once I get it to work! Thanks again